# Why is Bitlocker Encryption Immediatly Ready on System Partition

Tags: windows, windows-10, encryption, bitlocker

In re-installed Windows 10 and wanted to go this time with the integrated BitLocker encryption instead of a third party tool. I checked the settings and turned it on for my C: partition. It was immediately "on". When I did this for my 2nd partition on the same drive, it first did something for a while in the background before I could turn it on.

The behavior for my d: drive makes sense and fits with what I read, that Windows runs an encryption task in the background before you can then encrypt the key.

Why didn't it takes this time for the c: partition, does Windows already encrypt the drive by default but just doesn't encrypt the key. Or does it do both steps at the same time once activating it for the c: drive to make it simpler so the user doesn't have to go back?

I'm asking to be sure that it's properly activated and encrypted.

Comment: I do not have an answer so I cannot post one, but I had noticed the same thing. Bitlocker on windows 10 being instantly turned on on the C drive. I bet the C drive is automatically encrypted when windows 10 is installed, and only makes modifications to support "switching it on".

Comment: Windows 8.1+ has two encryption features.  Device Encryption and Bitlocker in both cases these features can use the storage devices encryption capabilities.  If we are talking about an SSD that process is nearly instantaneous

Comment: Ok, so basically would be like my first guess, by default windows "encrypts" the system drive, but the key is unencrypted. Then, depending on which type of encryption you choose, the keys are encrypted. Other partitions that are added are not encypted by default and first need to be converted to an encrypted storage and then the key is encrypted as well?